# How to redirect a page using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

My Scenario,

We Have wriitten a javascript in click on image to open the curtain raiser.When its done it should redirect to a page in website.How do we achive this? Please Help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd like a more detailed answer, you should provide your existing JavaScript. Otherwise, this is the best that I can do.

To redirect a page, change the `window.location.href` property:

```
window.location.href = "http://yourpage.com";
```

Comment: I have tried its working.Is it possible to redirect a aspx Page through this way.

Comment: @ShinyManu, Yes! You can redirect to any valid URL using this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <img src="images/myimage.jpg" name="btnHello" onclick="Test();"/>

function Test() {
window.location.href = "page to be redirected url";
 }
```

Something like this?